# C++ Separating elements of a vector with a comma

Tags: c++

I need to write a function that takes a single argument of type `const vector<long>&` that will return a string of all of the elements in the vector separated by commas, without a comma at the end.

I am only confused about how this problem is affected by including an address in the type. I believe I know how to create a general solution otherwise, so how does this `const vector<long>&` affect things, as opposed to `const vector<long>`?

Thanks.

Comment: That's a reference, not an address.

Comment: `const vector<long>` copies the whole object on a function call, but `const vector<long>&` doesn't. Also, that's a reference, not an address.